# Play sound only once Jquery

Tags: jquery, audio, hover, playback

I am trying to achieve something like this, upon hovering over an image, a sound is played, and I want the sound to be only played once, means after the initial hovering, the subsequent hovers will not trigger the sound to play anymore, currently i am trying this code, but it does not work

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#bg")[0].play();

var pring = 0;

$(function(){
$('#apDiv5').hover(
 function(){$("#phone")[0].play();},
 function(){$("#phone")[0].stop();
 pring++;
 if (pring > 1) {function(){$("#phone")[0].stop();}
 }});


});

});
```

Comment: If you are not dealing with a heavy sound app, don't play sounds at all please. In case, just add a `data-played` attribute to the element and set it to `true`, then check it on further hovers.

Comment: its not really sound heavy, but because I am doing a webcomic, so its to enhance the interactivity for the reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always add a special class to the element that played the audio and test for it already has that class:

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ifafip/3/edit)**</kbd>

```
$(function(){

   function playOnHover(el, audioFile){      
      $(el).addClass('played');
      var sound = new Audio( audioFile );   
      sound.play();      
   }

   $('#apDiv5').on('mouseenter', function(){
      if(!$(this).hasClass('played')) playOnHover( this, "sound.ogg" );
   });

});
```

Comment: much appreciated! will test it out !

Comment: @bunzbox as you can see that way you don't need to create `<audio>` elements all over the document. `new Audio()` will do the job.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#apDiv5').one('hover', function() {
```

This will make your hover event occur only once.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. http://jsfiddle.net/WAeQU/
Use jQuery `off` If the fiddle doesn't work, it should at least put you on your way.

Comment: I forgot to add this after the hov object `hov.init();`